# Change the service endpoint URLs in CRM2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a way to change the service endpoint URLs (under Developer Resources) for an MSCRM 2011 installation.
If a binding (A-record) was used for the CRM web site in IIS (eg. crm,crm.mydomain.com) then as part of installation MSCRM 2011 used "crm" for the service URLs 
i.e. 
"http://crm/MSCRMDEV/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"
"http://crm/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc"

Is there a way to reconfigure CRM to use the FQDN so that i can hit the services from outside the domain?
"http://crm.mydomain.com/MSCRMDEV/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"
"http://crm.mydomain.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 host names in the IIS bindings, "crm" and "crm.mydomain.com", I removed "crm" since it seems that crm 2011 can use only 1 host name
,but am not able to hit the services with the FQDN ( get a 404), the unqualified name works if I add the "crm" host header back in the bindings.

Comment: There was a missing step. In addition to the above you need to update the prefix node to include the domain name in web.config like so <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"> 
     <baseAddressPrefixFilters>   
  <clear/>
         <add prefix="http://crm.mydomain.com/"/>            
     </baseAddressPrefixFilters>   
   </serviceHostingEnvironment>                                   The web.config can be found under %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the default FQDN of the host machine (e.g.  crm01.mydomain.com) then typically you will need to setup an SPN for the URL you are using.  I cannot remember if the result is a 404 or a 401, but I would take a [look at configuring SPNs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/08/06/configuring-service-principal-names.aspx).

Comment: I have the SPNs set up for the host name(A-record)

Comment: I would check the Developer Resources under Settings -> Customizations to confirm that your changes in the CRM Deployment Manager are correct.

Comment: What happens when you click the link from CRM, a 404?  Have you setup the host header in IIS on CRM web site?  Can you pull up a static resource like an image using the FQDN?